# Windows Server 2012 R2 - Out of range signal

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, screen-resolution

I have recently bought Windows Server 2012 Essentials R2, I booted from DVD, it has loaded the files and I get the Windows logo and the loading circle. Then my monitor states the message:

> Out of range signal. Cannot display this video mode, change computer display input to 1680x1050 @60Hz

I was trying to setup WS. Can anyone can recommend anything?

Comment: Try a different monitor? Or use your remote console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During windows startup, try installing server core, rather than the "full" version.  As this won't install a GUI, if it installs without issue, the problem is likely to be in the default video drivers for whatever graphics card you have.  You may need to slipstream new drivers into the install media.

If you can't install the core version either, then the problem may lie with either the media you're using, or a problem with the hardware.  I've seen everything from bad video cards to bad power supplies cause issues with installing windows.  Try to test the media on another machine.